# Create timeline jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a timeline with Jetpack Compose and I see that it is literally impossible to create the lines for each row without spaces and with dynamic height depending on the text.
I have already tried with `Row` and with `ConstraintLayout` and the result is always the same.
I have found a cheat to make the `Box` visible by putting a `Text` in the middle otherwise the `Box` never gets a height.
What am I doing wrong?

```
@Composable
fun SessionMaterialRow(item:String){
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier) {
        val (lineReference,textReference) = createRefs()
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(lineReference){
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start,20.dp)
                width = Dimension.preferredValue(2.dp)
            }
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ){
            Text(" ")
        }
        DefaultText( modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(textReference){
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            start.linkTo(lineReference.start,10.dp)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
        },
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.title_session_number,"")+ " - " +"Text",
                style = title2Style
        )
    }
}
```

And I also have the "LazyColumn".

```
LazyColumn {
    items(listItems) {
        SessionMaterialRow(item = it)
    }
}
```

[image: Current vs Excpected]

Comment: Have you tried with Compose beta01? I have the expected result on my side using your code (I just replaced `DefaultText` by `Text`) using Compose beta01.

Comment: Thanks for answer, now with beta01 works fine!  But if you need more custom layout we can do that with  ```Layout{ measurables, constraints -> }``` thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

```
ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier) {
    val (lineReference,textReference) = createRefs()
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(lineReference){
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            start.linkTo(parent.start,20.dp)
            height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        }
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    ){
        Box(Modifier.width(2.dp))
    }
    Text( modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(textReference){
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
        start.linkTo(lineReference.start,10.dp)
        end.linkTo(parent.end)
    },
        //some text
    )
}
```

Comment: ***While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.***

Answer (score 0):

@van_fx answered is the simplest I am looking for.
works like charm.
His answers works like constraint layout in xml.
But you dont need multiple Box, use Spacer instead.

```
    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun Test() {
        val data = (1..3).toList()
        ConstraintLayout(Modifier) {
            val (lineReference,textReference) = createRefs()
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(lineReference) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start, 10.dp)
                        height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    }
                    .background(color = Color.Red)
                    .width(2.dp)
            )
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(textReference) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                start.linkTo(lineReference.start,10.dp)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }) {
                items(data) {
                    Text("jaklsdfjlkasf")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```